# Starting a Scheduled Task from Command prompt gives Access Denied

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a FreeFileSync setup that backups my files. I need non-admin users be able to launch the backup.

I created a scheduled task with the name "FreeFileSync PC Backup" and configured it without a trigger, but with run on demand option to initiate the backup, and run it with a useraccount that has admin privileges.

When I right-click the task from task scheduler, and choose run, it executes normally. If I create a batchfile and run `schtasks /run /tn "FreeFileSync PC Backup"` I get an ERROR: Access Denied.

I can right-click run as admin and login with an admin account and it will work, but that defeats its purpose.

I know this used to be possible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Scheduled Tasks. If the taskname contains a space, even while setup correctly, it will fail.

Delete the task, and recreate it, this time, just call it FreeFileSync, and
now `schtasks /run /tn FreeFileSync` will work.

Do note, if you use a domain joined pc, editing the task may change the user from DOMAIN\user to just user, which is the local user. If the user is local, it will not launch either and give an ERROR: Access Denied.